# autotest wont stop after a test fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, autotest

Here is my gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.6'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
end
```

Fairly straightforward and nothing unusual. On a passing test the autotest works great and stops like it should

```
Finished in 0.1158 seconds
4 examples, 0 failures
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby -rrubygems -S /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/bin/rspec --tty '/Users/alex/Sites/slacklog/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb'
```

but when a test fails its an endless loop that keeps failing

```
Failures:

  1) PagesController GET 'contact' Should have the proper title for the contact page
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector( "contact",
       expected following output to contain a <contact>Contact us</contact> tag:
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
       <title>Slacklog</title>
       <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/javascripts/application.js?1309037322" type="text/javascript"></script>
       </head>
       <body>

       <h1>Pages#contact</h1>
       <p>Find me in app/views/pages/contact.html.erb</p>


       </body>
       </html>
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.16647 seconds
5 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:30 # PagesController GET 'contact' Should have the proper title for the contact page
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby -rrubygems -S /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/bin/rspec --tty '/Users/alex/Sites/slacklog/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb'
...F.

Failures:
```

It keeps repeating

how do i stop this behavior

Answer (score 4):

There is a duplicate question that has the proper fix:
[Autotest inifinitely looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728179/autotest-inifinitely-looping)

The answer didn't fix it for me either, but it was because I was using webrat and webrat.log was being created, causing the tests to restart. So I modified their answer to include webrat.log

Here is the modified solution:

I found the solution. Probably has to do with OSX (running this on Leopard) changing the .DS_Store file in the folder or another temp file. Adding the following to my .autotest did the trick (this also prevents autotest looking at the index folder generated by Ferret).

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |at|
  %w{.git webrat.log vendor index .DS_Store ._}.each {|exception| at.add_exception(exception)}
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Try to uninstall your ZenTest gem and reinstall it via dependencies as:

```
sudo gem install autotest-rails
sudo gem install rspec-rails
```

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed it by putting the following in my `.autotest`
I know this is pretty late but I hope this will help someone :-)

```
at.add_exception %r{^./log}
```

My `.autotest` now looks like

```
# ./.autotest
Autotest.add_hook(:initialize) {|at|
  at.add_exception %r{^\.git}  # ignore Version Control System
  at.add_exception %r{^./tmp}  # ignore temp files, lest autotest will run again, and again...
  at.add_exception %r{^./spec/controllers}  # ignore controllers until cache has been fixed. auto test taking too long for now
  at.add_exception %r{^./log}  # ignore temp files, lest autotest will run again, and again...


  #  at.clear_mappings         # take out the default (test/test*rb)
  at.add_mapping(%r{^lib/.*\.rb$}) {|f, _|
    Dir['spec/**/*_spec.rb']
  }
  nil
}

require 'autotest/inotify'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, that worked for me! (without the require 'autotest/inotify')